# Change status bar colour in slide out menu

Tags: ios, ios7, menu, saslidemenu

I have a slide out menu and no matter what I try, I can't get the status bar area colour to change. I don't know what's wrong.

Picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2:

[image]

Picture 1 shows the app with the menu out. Picture 2 shows how the storyboard layout

I would have thought this would be simple as I've changed the global status bar colour using UINavigationBar appearance

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what color are you trying to get it? What color is it now? I don't really get which controller you mean...

Comment: The white area above the menu. I want that to be the same colour as the rest of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this slide menu library: 
https://github.com/arturdev/AMSlideMenu

Here you can customize status bar by any view.
Just call:

```
- (void)fixStatusBarWithView:(UIView *)view;
```

here view must be with height of 20px;

Answer (score 0):

The status bar in iOS7 is transparent. From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html):

> Because the status bar is transparent, the view behind it shows through. The style of the status bar refers to the appearance of its content, which includes items such as time, battery charge, and Wi-Fi signal. Use a UIStatusBarStyle constant to specify whether the status bar content should be dark (UIStatusBarStyleDefault) or light (UIStatusBarStyleLightContent).

So if it is not changing although you have altered the value in IB, you could try to set the value programmatically, like so:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
     return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; //or UIStatusBarStyleDefault
}
```

The above only changes the color of the text and icons in the status bar between black (`UIStatusBarStyleDefault`) and white (`UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`).

As stated by Apple, the bar itself is translucent, so it will be the same color as the view behind it.

Comment: When I change the background colour of "Slide menu root view controller", it still doesn't change the colour of the status bar area above the menu. It stays white no matter what background colour I set for "Slide menu root view controller"

Comment: Then that would mean that the menu doesn't take up the entire view, @user2900772 . It leaves space for the status bar. Which slide out menu are you using?

Comment: I thought it was something like that but I don't know how to fix it. The menu is called SASlideMenu.

Comment: You can even see in the screen shots in github that the view stops before the status bar. Try using [SWReveal Control](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), it has worked for me.

Comment: @user2900772, did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding another view the size of the status bar in Slide menu root view controller. Not sure why this works and changing the size of the view in Slide menu root view controller doesn't. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem @user2900772 . Post your fix as an answer so others can find the solution as well. Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that's using SASlideMenu and wondering how to do this. The fix is simple, just add a view to Slide Menu Root View Controller that covers the status bar area. When you change the background colour of this view, it colours the status bar area on the menu.