# iOS 7 Status bar transparency

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, statusbar

I'm stuck on something that looks trivial, but I really don't understand what's happening.

I'm compiling with iOS 7 SDK, and can't get the status bar to be transparent. It's fully black. In my .plist, `Status bar style` is `Transparent black style (alpha of 0.5)`. I've tried all the other options, but I couldn't get it to work.

I still need to support iOS 6, but I'd expect iOS 7 status bar to be transparent by default, right ?

Any idea on what could cause this ?

Thanks

Comment: iOS 7 status bar is transparent by default. I just answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20891693/2535467).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll answer to my own question, sorry about the waste of time.

My mistake was, the status bar **was** transparent. But for whatever reason, calling

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

changed the top inset of my scrollview from `0.f` to `20.f`... So, I had a black background under my status bar, and therefore, a black status bar.

Thanks anyway !

Comment: For the record, the error came from `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` set to `YES`.

Comment: You just made my day. Had the same problem with initial display of a view inside a UIPageViewController. The UIPageViewController went under the status bar, but the initial page in the controller would be offset below the status bar. I was also using setNavigationBarHidden with the animation to display the page controller. Setting automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to NO in the page controller fixed it. You just ended a day of banging my head against the wall...thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

Add this code to your .m file:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, that's pretty much every SO answer about that. No matter what `View controller-based status bar appearance` is set to in this info.plist, this function isn't called (can't fire a breakpoint, nor an NSLog)

Answer (score -4):

hope this helps

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```